# ScrollView in SYSTEM_TYPE_ALERT is blurred

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

I have an android app that displays an system alert from a service:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(view, params);
```

I have set view to a GridView, Scrollable TextView, and a Gallery and on all of them if I scroll the images/text blend together.  Everything is blurred together.  It is as if the new image/text is drawn on the screen but the old image/text is not removed.  Any idea on how to fix this?  Does anyone have an example of a TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT where the content is scrollable?